# can I use singleTon to create a globle lock?

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, singleton

For example, I create a singleTon lock class. Then I use the locker whatever I want, for example another singleTon

```
class SIN
{
public:
    static SIN& getSIN()
    {
        static SIN *sin = new SIN;
        return *sin;
    }

    void insertMap(const int& id,const string& str)
    {
        locker::getLocker().lock();
        subMap[id] = str;
        locker::getLocker().unlock();
        return;
    }

    string getStr(const int& id)
    {
        string str = "";
        locker::getLocker().lock();
        if(subMap.find(id) != subMap.end()){
            str = subMap[id];
        }
        locker::getLocker().unlock();
        return str;
    }
private:
    SIN(){}
    SIN(const SIN&) = delete;
    SIN& operator=(const SIN&) = delete;

private:
    map<int,string> subMap;
}
```

I don't find this usage in network, will there be any potential problems during using?

Comment: Just some first order comments :I wouldn't use "new" on a singleton, nobody is going to call the destructor. Just use static SIN sin; return sin.  For locking I would just use a std::mutex + std::unique_lock combo where the mutex is a member of SIN.  (your code is currently not exception safe since you have separate calls to lock/unlock, std::unique_lock prevents that),

Comment: I don't really see any advantages of a global lock. But with global locking debugging deadlocks could become a nightmare.

Comment: What benefit does this have over just having the mutex as a member of `SIN`? Singletons should be used sparingly (if at all) and I'm not sure I see the point of introducing one here

Comment: I'll change the SIN class to a thread-safe class with std::mutex + std::lock_guard or std::unique_lock after studied. But when I deal with shared vectors at different thread, should I use a global lock or try to make a class with a mutex?